# How to use EJS inside HTML attributes?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I have the following two cases where I want to use an EJS tag inside an HTML attribute.

**CASE 1:**

```
<input
   style="background-image: url(<%= img.URL %>)"
/>
```

**CASE 2:**

```
<input
    onchange="handleCheckboxChange(<%= img.URL %>)"
/>
```

I am unable to figure out why is it not working. The `img` object is passed correctly while rendering the template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case 2 translates to the following:

```
<input
    onchange="handleCheckboxChange(https://example.org)"
/>
```

Which is a syntax error

You need to wrap them inside quotes:

```
<input
    onchange="handleCheckboxChange('<%= img.URL %>')"
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for the same, the **ejs tags need to be wrapped inside quotes**.

**SOLUTION FOR CASE 1**

```
<input
   style="background-image: url('<%= img.URL %>')"
/>
```

**SOLUTION FOR CASE 2**

```
<input
    onchange="handleCheckboxChange('<%= img.URL %>')"
/>
```